# meteor spacebars nested each property by child property name

Tags: meteor, spacebars

In Spacebars, can I access an outer-each’s property by name of an inner each property. I.e. ? `access ymBStocks.price via via {{../{{title}}}}`

More complete example

```
<template name="ymbStockstable">    
<table class="table table-hover table-ymbStocks">
   <thead>
       <tr>
        {{#each columns}}
            <th>{{title}}</th>
        {{/each}}
       </tr>
   </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{#each ymbStocks}}
      <tr>
        {{#each columns}}
            <td>{{../columns.title}}</td>
        {{/each}}
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
      </tbody>
</table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

w3jimmy @w3jimmy 14:09
create a helper to get the property of an object

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
   getProperty: function (obj_name, prop_name){
       if (obj_name.hasOwnProperty(prop_name)){
           return obj_name.prop_name;
       } 
   }
})
```

and then in spacebars you do like this:

```
{{#each ymbStock in ymbStocks}}

    ...

 {{#each column in columns}}


     <td>price: {{getProperty column.title ymbStock.price}}</td>


 {{/each}}

{{/each}}`
```

I just spit it out, without testing...